# R Shiny app - How do I automatically use my most recent output as part of the input when the user next triggers the app to refresh?

Tags: r, shiny

I'm a newcomer to Shiny, I'm building a Shiny app with a text box. It's for predictive text, so the user types something into this box, and the app calls a function that returns some possibilities for the word the user is currently typing.

To do this it scans some files of words/sequences of words, and extracts a subset containing all the rows that match what the user has so far typed (or part of what's been typed).

As the user continues typing, it's not always necessary to re-open and re-subset an entire file - this thing will run faster if I carry forward the previous subset so that that can be subsetted further based on further user input. With this in mind, my function returns a list with the suggestions and the subset they came from.

How do I make it so that the file subset is passed back to the function, ready for use when the user types their next character? Has anyone got a quick example of this being done?

*PS. I notice 20 people have read this without replying, is there something wrong with how I've asked this?

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented a minimal example of your idea. It loads the initial data into a global variable, and a reactive block updates the global sublist variable. The sublist is written on the main panel, and length of the sublist is printed on the console in order to indicate that the list is in fact getting shorter with increasing letter count.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(
    textInput("text", "Text to be searched")
  ),
  mainPanel(
     textOutput("textOut")
     )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
wordlist <- c("a", "ab", "abc", "abcd", "abcde", "different")
# With pre-defined file
# wordlist <- read.delim("/path/to/the/file.txt", header = FALSE, sep = ",")
sublist <- NULL

newList <- reactive({
  if (input$text == ""){
    sublist <<- wordlist
  } else {
    temp <- sublist
    sublist <<- NULL
    sublist <<- temp[grepl(input$text, temp)]
  }
  sublist
})
output$textOut <- renderText({
 newList <- newList()
 cat(paste("Length of the sublist is: ", length(sublist), "\n"))
 newList
})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

For what it is worth, doing this recursively with global variables might not be a good idea (changing global variables inside reactives is not that good practice overall, removing letters from the search word should at least trigger a new search from scratch etc.) But as a basis, you shouldn't open and read the files every time user enters a new letter, the list should be loaded only once. Skipping the continuous file opening/closing will affect the running time more than using the subsets.